# Incompatible types: 'WideChar' and 'Char' delphi 7

Tags: delphi, error-handling, delphi-7

I am getting an error in my delphi code when using shellexecute to call an external progrem

```
procedure TReceiverMainForm.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
  args:string;
begin
  mmoResult.Clear;
//  args := ' /d='  + TIdURI.URLEncode(Trim(sSearch)) + ' /t=ReceiverMainForm /s=30 /m=1'
args := ' /q='  + httpencode(Trim(txtSearch.Text)) + ' /t=ReceiverMainForm /s='+Trim(txtS.Text)+' /m='+Trim(txtM.Text);
  ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'YTD.exe', pWideChar(args), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;
```

how do i reslve this error?

Comment: Perhaps, you should try `ShellExecuteW` instead.

Comment: @Andriy That would fix the compile error, but the code would fail at runtime. Would need args to be WideString also. Since args is built out of 8 bit data, there's nothing to be gained from using the wide API.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Ah, yes, you are right. Don't know why I didn't pay attention to `args`'s type. Even if it worked, there would be no point in using the Unicode version instead of the ANSI one, as the original string wasn't a Unicode one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is defined like so

```
function ShellExecute(hWnd: HWND; Operation, FileName, Parameters,
  Directory: PChar; ShowCmd: Integer): HINST; stdcall;
```

So the issue is which you are casting the `args` variable to a `PWideChar` instead of a `PChar`.

Try this code

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'YTD.exe', PChar(args), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Remember that Delphi 7 pre-dates the Unicode Delphi development. And so `PChar` is an alias for the 8 bit character type, `PAnsiChar`.